# How can an injustice "stand"?

Tags: metaphors

I understand the usage of "stand" in these:

> 1 "The review board let the decision ***stand***"
>   2 "The offer/agreement still ***stands***"
>   3 "They allow the ruling to ***stand***"

But I am confused about a phrase I found on the web:

> "The government let an injustice ***stand***"

An injustice is not something official.  It is just an action.  So, how does it "*stand*"?  Could it be an error?  Is there a dictionary definition that would fit this example?

Comment: If we can "let something go", we should be able to say "let something stand" as well.

Answer (score 1):

Officialness is not at all part of the definition of **stand** in this (or any?) sense.

It means *to not be changed*.  For instance, someone might consider editing an ELL.SE post, but decide to let it **stand**, meaning deciding not to change it and leaving it as it is.

The closest English synonyms are "endure", "persist", and "abide", though they are only approximate.

Answer (score 0):

See ['stand' on Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stand), specifically:

> verb
>
> 5. to be or exist in a specified state or condition

So, substituting:

> The government let an injustice be

There's probably also an omitted, understood meaning, based on what would normally be expected:

> The government let an injustice be (rather than rectify it)

Comment: But if the injustice refers to a past event, then the injustice certainly is already completed.  So, it cannot possibly "continue in effect".

Comment: @banner I probably didn't make it clear, I think that there's something else omitted there, which would be an understood meaning: "The government let an injustice continue (rather than rectify it)"

Comment: @banner  The better definition for this case may be `to be or exist in a specified state or condition`. "The government let a justice be (rather than rectify it). Does that clear things up? I will edit my answer.